# Beautiful Soup Traceback on First Attempt

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, traceback, urlopen

Hello I'm new to python and Beautiful Soup. I have downloaded BS4 with pip install and am attempting to do some web scaping. I have looked through a lot of help guides and haven't been able to get my BeautifulSoup() to work through the cmd compiler. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
print(tag.get('href', None))
```

This is the traceback I get with an URL input:

```
C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding>python urllinks_get.py
Enter - http://www.dr-chuck.com/page1.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\urllinks_get.py", line 21, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\__init__.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\__init__.py", line 239, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 164, in feed
    parser.feed(markup)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\html\parser.py", line 110, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\html\parser.py", line 170, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\html\parser.py", line 344, in parse_starttag
    self.handle_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 62, in handle_starttag
    self.soup.handle_starttag(name, None, None, attr_dict)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\__init__.py", line 404, in handle_starttag
    self.currentTag, self._most_recent_element)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 1001, in __getattr__
    return self.find(tag)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 1238, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 1259, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 516, in _find_all
    strainer = SoupStrainer(name, attrs, text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 1560, in __init__
    self.text = self._normalize_search_value(text)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\bs4\element.py", line 1565, in _normalize_search_value
    if (isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, collections.Callable) or hasattr(value, 'match')
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
```

Really would like to continue my online classes so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Unable to reproduce, your code works fine on my machine. Are you sure you're using python**3**?

Comment: Yes I'm using python 3.10.7

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. I had installed beautifulsoup4 as well as used the bs4 folder in the same directory as my program ran in. I didn't realize they would interfere with one another. As soon as I removed the bs4 folder from the directory my program ran fine :)